# Correlation of financial returns: how to account for different frequencies?

Tags: time-series, correlation

If you had to calculate a correlation between two financial return time-series, on what frequency would it make sense to do so?

Yearly returns? Monthly? Weekly? Daily?

What is the norm here?

The issue with yearly returns seems to be that you are missing out on a lot of data.

The issue with daily returns seems to be you are including too much noise. On top of that, many time series do not even have daily returns, but e.g. weekly, so if one time-series is weekly and the other is daily, you need to embed the daily returns into a weekly time-series anyways.

What are the rules of thumbs here?

Comment: I would chose a time horizon that’s in accordance with the application at hand. If, for example, I do some monthly rebalancing I would go for monthly sampled returns, and correlations based on those.